# GridView Reader returns repeating values ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable that contains items I read from a GridView column.
The GridView I'm reading looks like this:

```
 SELECT      COURSE       NAME

 Select      Course_1     USER_1
 Select      Course_2     USER_2
 Select      Course_3     USER_3
```

This is my code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim dtcopy As New Datatable()

dt.Columns.Add("File",GetType(String))

For Each row As GridViewRow In GV_PDBC.Rows
            For i As Integer = 1 To GV_PDBC.Rows.Count - 1
                strname = row.Cells(2).Text
                 dt.Rows.Add(strname)

                 dtcopy.Merge(dt, True, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)
           Next
        Next
```

It's reading the column repeatedly. Here is the datatable result:

```
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_1
 USER_2
 USER_2
 ...
```

I think I am just missing something. Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: i couldn't understand why are you using "For i As Integer = 1 To GV_PDBC.Rows.Count - 1" loop as you are already using Foreach loop

Comment: Whats the deal with dtcopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of writing code for this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim dtcopy As New Datatable()

dt.Columns.Add("File",GetType(String))

'This loop will iterate all gridview rows
For Each row As GridViewRow In GV_PDBC.Rows 

    'Determine the row type.
    if row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        strname = row.Cells(2).Text
        dt.Rows.Add(strname)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. I also removed the dtcopy.Merge(dt..) and I got what I need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Repeating value is due bcz of the second loop for,

```
For i As Integer = 1 To GV_PDBC.Rows.Count - 1

Next
```

you need to remove for loop  the result will be

USER_1

USER_2

USER_3

the code will be :

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dtcopy As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("File", GetType(String))
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GV_PDBC.Rows
        strname = row.Cells(2).Text
        dt.Rows.Add(strname)
        dtcopy.Merge(dt, True, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)
    Next
```